# ARX Models in Gekko

Tags: python, pandas, gekko

Is there any other way to introduce an ARX model in GEKKO than the arx() function?

Here is the reason: I am trying to identify a model of a system as an ARX model. First I tried to use sysid() and axr() (functions in GEKKO) to identify my system and then simulate the result and see if the output is as desired. When using small data samples (10 min and 1h) the identification with sysid() was good, but with a large sample (5h), the identification results were not so good. So I tried to identify my system with code I wrote, using linear regression and a delayed dependent variable to identify an ARX model (I used the same data set for sysid() and my code). The problem is that if I used my code to get the a,b and c parameters for the dictionary p and then used this dictionary for the arx(p) function to create a simulation, the temperature curve is logical but the temperature values are not despite the good prediction results.

The identification results with the Linear regression are better than the identification using sysid().

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code i used for Linear Regression:

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b_dataframe = pd.read_csv("Temp.txt")
b_dataframe.columns = ["Temp"]
a_dataframe = pd.read_csv("State.txt")
a_dataframe.columns = ["State"]
df = b_dataframe.join(a_dataframe)

# autocorrelation_plot(df["T[C]"])
X = df.drop("Temp", axis=1) # Drop column T[U]
X.loc[:, "lagged_T_1"] = df["Temp"].shift(1).fillna(0)
#X.loc[:, "lagged_T_2"] = df["T[C]"].shift(2).fillna(0)
y = df["Temp"]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
#defined a function for linear regression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
# Train data points --> the rest is for prediction.
n_train = 2500
# just a split 
x_train, x_test = X.iloc[:n_train,:], X.iloc[n_train:,:]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[:n_train], y.iloc[n_train:]

#model fitting/ train.
#Fit x, y values used for train to the given data.
lin_reg.fit(x_train.values,y_train.values)

# test: With the rest of data points, test the results of the prediction.
y_pred = pd.Series(lin_reg.predict(x_test.values), name="T_pred")
print(lin_reg.coef_)

plt.plot(y_pred.values)
plt.plot(y_test.values)
#plt.text(1, 1, metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
plt.legend(["Prediction", "Actual"])
plt.ylim([11.6, 15])
lin_reg.coef_, lin_reg.intercept_
```

Simulation results Using Gekko and coefficient from linear regression:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2vnL.png

Code for Simulation:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

na = 1# Number of A coefficients
nb = 1 # Number of B coefficients
ny = 1 # Number of outputs
nu = 1 # Number of inputs

# A (na x ny)
# actual A,B,C values are from 5 h data
A = np.array([[0.960187147]])
# B (ny x (nb x nu))
B= np.array([[[-0.000361506092]]])
C = np.array([ 0.565842747871903])

# create parameter dictionary
# parameter dictionary p['a'], p['b'], p['c']
# a (coefficients for a polynomial, na x ny)
# b (coefficients for b polynomial, ny x (nb x nu))
# c (coefficients for output bias, ny)
p = {'a':A,'b':B,'c':C}


m = GEKKO(remote=True)
y,u = m.arx(p)

# load inputs
#tf = 719 # final time
u1 = np.append(np.ones(500),np.zeros(500),0)
u2 = np.append(u1, np.ones(500),0)
u3 = np.append(u2, np.zeros(500),0)
u4 = np.append(u3, np.ones(500),0)
u5 = np.append(u4, np.zeros(936),0)
u[0].value = u5


mv = y[0]
cv= u[0]
mv.value = 14.2

m.time = np.linspace(0,3436,3436)
m.options.imode = 4
m.options.nodes= 2
#m.options.SOLVER = 1
# simulate
m.solve()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get equivalent `sysid` results if you use the option `pred='meas'` instead of the default `pred='model'` and use `shift='calc'` instead of the default `shift='init'`. The linear regression that you are performing may give biased results while the default options in `sysid()` give unbiased results because it uses an output error form. The difference is that the next `y[k]` is predicted from the prior model value instead of the prior measurement for `y[k-1]`. I verified that the Gekko predictions are correct with a quick Excel calculation and a single step.

[image: Step response]

Here is an equivalent model response in Gekko but with more steps.

[image: More steps]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

na = 1# Number of A coefficients
nb = 1 # Number of B coefficients
ny = 1 # Number of outputs
nu = 1 # Number of inputs

# A (na x ny)
# actual A,B,C values are from 5 h data
A = np.array([[0.960187147]])
# B (ny x (nb x nu))
B= np.array([[[-0.000361506092]]])
C = np.array([ 0.565842747871903])

# create parameter dictionary
# parameter dictionary p['a'], p['b'], p['c']
# a (coefficients for a polynomial, na x ny)
# b (coefficients for b polynomial, ny x (nb x nu))
# c (coefficients for output bias, ny)
p = {'a':A,'b':B,'c':C}


m = GEKKO(remote=True)
y,u = m.arx(p)

# load inputs
#tf = 719 # final time
u1 = np.append(np.ones(500),np.zeros(500),0)
u2 = np.append(u1, np.ones(500),0)
u3 = np.append(u2, np.zeros(500),0)
u4 = np.append(u3, np.ones(500),0)
u5 = np.append(u4, np.zeros(936),0)
u[0].value = u5

cv = y[0]
mv= u[0]
cv.value = 14.2

# for time steps of 1 use final time of 3435
m.time = np.linspace(0,3435,3436)
m.options.imode = 4
m.options.nodes= 2
#m.options.SOLVER = 1
# simulate
m.solve()

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,cv.value,'b-',label='CV')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,mv.value,'r--',label='MV')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Here is a way to build the model without the ARX function:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = 0.960187147
B = -0.000361506092
C = 0.565842747871903

m = GEKKO(remote=True)

u1 = np.append(np.ones(500),np.zeros(500),0)
u2 = np.append(u1, np.ones(500),0)
u3 = np.append(u2, np.zeros(500),0)
u4 = np.append(u3, np.ones(500),0)
u5 = np.append(u4, np.zeros(936),0)
u = u5

cv = m.Array(m.Var,3436)

time = np.linspace(0,3435,3436)
m.options.imode = 1

m.Equation(cv[0]==14.2)
for i in range(3435):
    m.Equation(cv[i+1] == A * cv[i] + B * u[i] + C)

# simulate
m.solve()
```

You can build the ARX model with `IMODE=1` in Python if you manage the time series values with unique variable names at each time point. Note that your `MV` and `CV` labels are swapped in the example that you posted. The `CV` is the controlled variable and is the output predicted value. The `MV` is that value that can be adjusted manually by the operator or else adjusted by the solver.

If you look inside the sysid function, you'll also see an example of how to build the ARX model without the help of the ARX function but for the multivariate case. This is more complicated so I don't recommend using this approach.

```py
syid.Raw('Objects')
syid.Raw('  sum_a[1:ny] = sum(%i)'%na)
syid.Raw('  sum_b[1:ny][1::nu] = sum(%i)'%nbk)
syid.Raw('End Objects')
syid.Raw('  ')
syid.Raw('Connections')
syid.Raw('  a[1:na][1::ny] = sum_a[1::ny].x[1:na]')
syid.Raw('  b[1:nb][1::nu][1:::ny] = sum_b[1:::ny][1::nu].x[1:nb]')
syid.Raw('  sum_a[1:ny] = sum_a[1:ny].y')
syid.Raw('  sum_b[1:ny][1::nu] = sum_b[1:ny][1::nu].y')
syid.Raw('End Connections')
syid.Raw('  ')
syid.Raw('Constants')
syid.Raw('  n = %i' %n)
syid.Raw('  nu = %i'%nu)
syid.Raw('  ny = %i'%ny)
syid.Raw('  na = %i'%na)
syid.Raw('  nb = %i'%nbk)
syid.Raw('  m = %i'%m)
syid.Raw('  ')
syid.Raw('Parameters')
syid.Raw('  a[1:na][1::ny] = 0.9 !>= 0.00001 <= 0.9999999')
syid.Raw('  b[1:nb][1::nu][1:::ny] = 0')
syid.Raw('  c[1:ny] = 0')
syid.Raw('  u[1:n][1::nu]')
syid.Raw('  y[1:m][1::ny]')
syid.Raw('  z[1:n][1::ny]')
syid.Raw('  Ks[1:ny][1::nu] = 1')
syid.Raw('  ')
syid.Raw('Variables')
syid.Raw('  y[m+1:n][1::ny] = 0')
syid.Raw('  sum_a[1:ny] = 0 !<= 1')
syid.Raw('  sum_b[1:ny][1::nu] = 0')
syid.Raw('  K[1:ny][1::nu] = 0 >=-1e8 <=1e8')
syid.Raw('  ')
syid.Raw('Equations')
if pred=='model':
    # use model to predict next y (Output error)
    eqn = '  y[m+1:n][1::ny] = a[1][1::ny]*y[m:n-1][1::ny]'
else:
    # use measurement to predict next y (ARX)
    eqn = '  y[m+1:n][1::ny] = a[1][1::ny]*z[m:n-1][1::ny]'
for j in range(1,nu+1):
    eqn += '+b[1][%i][1::ny]*u[m:n-1][%i]'%(j,j,)
    for i in range(2,nbk+1): 
        eqn += '+b[%i][%i][1::ny]*u[m-%i:n-%i][%i]'%(i,j,i-1,i,j,)
if pred=='model':
    # use model to predict next y (Output error)
    seqn = '+a[%i][1::ny]*y[m-%i:n-%i][1::ny]'
else:
    # use measurement to predict next y (ARX)
    seqn = '+a[%i][1::ny]*z[m-%i:n-%i][1::ny]'        
for i in range(2,na+1): 
    eqn += seqn%(i,i-1,i,)
eqn += '+c[1::ny]'
syid.Raw(eqn)
syid.Raw('')
syid.Raw('  K[1:ny][1::nu] * (1 - sum_a[1:ny]) = Ks[1:ny][1::nu] * sum_b[1:ny][1::nu]')        
syid.Raw('  minimize %e * (y[m+1:n][1::ny] - z[m+1:n][1::ny])^2'%objf)
syid.Raw('  minimize 1e-3 * a[1:na][1::ny]^2')
syid.Raw('  minimize 1e-3 * b[1:nb][1::nu][1:::ny]^2')
syid.Raw('  minimize 1e-3 * c[1:ny]^2')
```

Comment: Here is a more complete description of ARX Models in Python Gekko: https://apmonitor.com/dde/index.php/Main/AutoRegressive I recently developed the Data-Driven Engineering course that includes content on time-series modeling and control.